# List javascript array in alfresco freemarkuer template

Tags: javascript, templates, alfresco, freemarker

Basically I the have following JavaScript arrays filled:

```
array1 = new Array(1, 2, 3);
array2 = new Array("Title1", "Title2", "Title3");
array3 = new Array("10-02-2017", "11-02-2017", "12-02-2017");

bigArray = new Array();
bigArray.push(array1);
bigArray.push(array2);
bigArray.push(array3);

model.entry = bigArray;
```

Now in the ftl file I would like to get the following output out of the ftl File:

```
1, Title1, 10-02-2017
2, Title2, 11-02-2017
3, Title3, 12-02-2017
```

How do I "call" such a usecase? Ich haven't even an idea what to google for, so i could read manuals and stuff. Can you help or recommend some useful tutorial?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you edit your question with that code also?

Comment: I would call this "mapping". As you are mapping values into a new array.

Comment: I don't understand, you mean that you want to want to have the output rendered as you have specified ? Because in this case you can easily iterate the arrays, either within a WebScript, or a Script that use the transformationService, both of them relying on a .ftl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by splitting my bigArray into the single Arrays.

So I have no longer:

```
bigArray = new Array();
bigArray.push(array1);
bigArray.push(array2);
bigArray.push(array3);

model.entry = bigArray;
```

Now I have:

```
model.ids = array1;
model.titles = array2;
model.dates = array3;
```

And then I output them like this:

```
IDs:
<#list ids as id>
  ${id}<#sep>,
</#list><br>

Titles:
<#list titles as title>
  ${title}<#sep>,
</#list><br>

Dates:
<#list dates as date>
  ${date}<#sep>,
</#list><br>
```

So my output looks a bit different:

```
IDs: 1,2,3
Titles: Title1, Title2, Title3
Dates: 10-02-2017, 11-02-2017, 12-02-2017
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the point is that you want to iterate through three arrays interlaced. In that case I would just iterate through the common index:

```
<#list 0 ..< entry[0]?size as i>
${entry[0][i]}, ${entry[1][i]}, ${entry[2][i]}
</#list>
```

Comment: do you know any manual or something where i can read trough to understand how this code example works?

Comment: @MarkusFsx The official FreeMarker documentation... In particular http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_direct_seuqence, if that's the part you don't understand.

Comment: got it now, see the response I posted. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON object instead of multiple arrays to map your objects, otherwise here is the FTL code to get your output.

```
<#list entry[0] as item0>
  ${item0}, 
  <#list entry[1] as item1>
    <#if item1?index == item0?index>
      ${item1}, 
    </#if>
  </#list>
  <#list entry[2] as item2>
    <#if item2?index == item0?index>
      ${item2}
    </#if>
  </#list>
  <br />
</#list>
```

think about handling exceptions if such index doesn't exist.

Comment: Why iterate through the other two lists if you already have the index? You could just write `${item0}, ${entry[1][item0?index]}, ${entry[2][item0?index]}<br />`.

Comment: do you know any manual or something where i can read trough to understand how this code example works?